# sublime text3 How to sort folders on Sidebar by "Last modified" and not alphabetically?

Tags: sublimetext3

Anyone help me for this.

I always wish to work with sublime text 3 by creating project,
And include folders on it like this,
[image: Check screenshot]

This problem is every time I create a new folder for new website but it's goes to mixed in the whole folder, I've to bother to find among the folders.

I would like to show at the top/first, could you tell me if there anyway for this please ?

Comment: yes, me too have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, changing the sort order in the sidebar is not currently possible (as at build 3133).

There is an open feature request for the sidebar sort order here:

- https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/328

Comment: Thank you for the information @Keith Hall, would be better if we a chance for any additional plugins for this!.